# Хранение старого значения после обработки события JS

Tags: javascript, события

Здравствуйте. При возникновении события необходимо хранить предыдущие значения. 
Например:

```
var old_value = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var new_value = window.pageYOffset;
  if(new_value!=old_value)
    ...//какие-то действия
    old_value = new_value;
  }
}
```

Но так `old_value` оказывается в глобальной области видимости, что ни есть хорошо.

Почитал про [замыкания](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures) и [привязку контекста](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind), но не уверен что это то что нужно для решения данной проблемы.

Подскажите, как грамотно реализовывается такая задача? 
Или это возможно только с использованием глобальных переменных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

действительно, можно хранить в родительской области видимости, но можно этого и избежать, используя например объект:

```js
(function() { // это как раз замыкание, чтобы не делать наш конструктор глобальным
  function scrollHandler() {
    return this.handle.bind(this); // вернем хэндлер из конструтора, прибьем к нему this гвоздями.
  };
  scrollHandler.prototype.handle = function(e) {
    var new_value = window.pageYOffset;
    if (new_value != this.old_value) {
      console.log(this.old_value, new_value);
      this.old_value = new_value;
    }
  }
  window.onscroll = new scrollHandler(); // этот обработчик изолирован и его состояние никуда, кроме обработчика событий не торчит.
})();
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000vh;
}
```

---

но можно и проще, что-то не сообразил под вечер:

```js
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var new_value = window.pageYOffset;
  if (new_value != this.old_value) {
    console.log(this.old_value, new_value);
    this.old_value = new_value;
  }
}.bind({}); // этот обработчик изолирован и его состояние никуда, кроме обработчика событий не торчит. bind меняет контекст на новый объект.
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000vh;
}
```